# Play Music through Microsoft Groove using Google Now?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, music-player

I recently switched over from Windows Phone to Android. Since I'm still mostly in the Windows ecosystem, I have a subscription to (and thousands of songs in) Microsoft Groove. On my old Windows Phone I was used to telling Cortana to play a playlist while I was driving, which was great. Is it possible to make Google Now do the same? (Perhaps by making Groove the default music player, if that is possible?)

Solutions involving Google Play Music are not what I'm looking for, since I have an ongoing subscription to and large library in Groove.

Device is a Nexus 6P running Android 6.0. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why not download [Cortana for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.cortana)? It may be able to send direct commands to Groove, if Groove doesn't respond to generic `Media Play` system-wide events sent to the default app.

Comment: However, I do believe you can get this to work with Google Now as well. If you can't find a way to set Groove as the default app, uninstall all other music apps (stock music app will be most difficult to remove) and Groove should receive all system-wide events.

Comment: @AaronGillion I disabled Google Play Music through the application manager, but now Google Now just searches Google if I tell it to play music (as expected). Groove doesn't appear to let me set defaults - I'll blame Microsoft for that one. As for Cortana - I would love to, but unfortunately it's not available in my region (Canada).